# What global warming level would be needed to keep the dew point of some place above the temperature of the lungs for at least 1 month per year?

Tags: water, temperature, climate-change

Title might be a bit hard to understand but let me explain : when the dew point is above humans temperature (37℃) the [water condenses in the lungs which are at a lower temperature than the air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_of_the_Crystals) which means mammals die drowned by breathing the air. Of course, such a level is different and above the 35℃ wet bulb temperature.

My question is as follows : what’s the current estimated global warming level that would maintain such fatal dew point continuously during an entire month in at least 1 place of the world each year (i.e making everyone willing to kill or get killed for wanting to flee).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141558/discussion-on-question-by-user2284570-what-global-warming-level-would-be-needed).

Comment: Sounds a little complicated maybe you could make the question especially the title little bit more clear.